# AppleScript doesn't work if Spaces in File/Folder path

Tags: applescript

This works ok, UNLESS there are Spaces (and maybe other special characters) anywhere in the folder path. if there are spaces, then the check for folder exists fails, how can I make it work?

```
tell application "Finder"
    set mySaveASDelimiters to AppleScript's text item delimiters

    set myScriptFilePath to (path to me)
    set mySourceFolder to folder of myScriptFilePath
    set myFileAliasList to the entire contents of mySourceFolder

    set myPOSIXSourceFolder to URL of mySourceFolder
    set myPOSIXSourceFolder to characters 8 thru -1 of myPOSIXSourceFolder as string

    repeat with myFile in myFileAliasList
        set myFileName to name of myFile
        log "myFileName: " & myFileName

        if (myFileName ends with ".txt") then
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "."
            set myFolderName to first text item of myFileName
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to mySaveASDelimiters


            set myFolderPath to myPOSIXSourceFolder & myFolderName as string
            log "myFolderPath: " & myFolderPath

            tell application "System Events"
                if not (exists folder myFolderPath) then
                    beep
                    display dialog "Could not find Folder for File: " & myFileName
                    return {}
                end if
            end tell

        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

---

Lets make this easier:

```
set myScriptFilePath to (path to me)
set mySourceFolder to folder of myScriptFilePath
set myPOSIXSourceFolder to POSIX path of mySourceFolder
```

I get an error on myPOSIXSourceFolder, why! I just want the current folder path in POSIX notation! I have fixed it now:

```
set myAppFile to (path to me)
set myAppFilePath to ((path to me as text) & "::")  --Magic I was looking for
set myAppFolder to POSIX path of (myAppFilePath) as string
set myFilePath to myAppFolder & "ModTest1"

log "myAppFilePath: " & myAppFilePath
log "myAppFile: " & myAppFile
log "myAppFolder: " & myAppFolder
log "myFilePath: " & myFilePath


set thePath to myFilePath

tell application "System Events"
    if exists folder thePath then
        beep
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: The URL has spaces and special characters escaped, so you would need to deal with them or use another method such as `POSIX path`.

Comment: I'm not sure where about in the Script you mean, please give an example.

Comment: You are setting `myPOSIXSourceFolder` to a URL, which has non-ASCII characters and spaces replaced with "%" and hex digits.  If all you are wanting is a POSIX path, you can use the `POSIX path` property of a file or alias (see the [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-SW3).

Comment: That doesn't work, see above.

Comment: You are still mangling paths for every file in a folder by stripping the first 7 characters, and it looks like you are also trying to strip the extension in some cases.  What _exactly_ are you trying to find?

Comment: You can edit your entire post if needed, the change history will be there if anyone wants to look at earlier versions.  And it would still be useful to describe what you are trying to do - if all you did was change those 3 lines, you are still mangling file paths, but I can't tell what you are looking for.

Comment: Fixed it now, see the end of the post

Answer (score 0):

```
set myAppFile to (path to me)
set myAppFilePath to POSIX path of ((path to me as text) & "::")  --Magic I was looking for
```

This is the answer I was looking for, its basically the syntax takes a bit of getting used to, one of the problems with AppleScript......

Comment: That's a pretty odd and unusual syntax, in a `Finder` tell block this does the same: `set myAppFilePath to POSIX path of (container of myAppFile as text)`

Comment: I avoid using the Finder if I can